# Customizing DiaglogFragment Window

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I want to resize the width and height of my DiaglogFragment window but the code below does not give the resized version of my dialog window but instead the main activity view has been modified. I also tried to modify the xml but still a fail.

I am not sure how to use `getDialog()` on this one, still getting some errors.  `dialog_fragment.xml` is the layout that I want to be modified such that the width and height should be fully customized.

```
public static class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment;
public DialogFragment newInstace() {
     dialogFragment = new TestDialogFragment();
    Log.d("Dialog Create", "sdf1");
    return dialogFragment;
}



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),
                                      R.style.PopupTheme);
    builder.setTitle("TestDialogFragment");
    builder.setView(getContentView());
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    Log.d("Dialog Create", "sdf2");
    return dialog;

}

private View getContentView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    LayoutParams params = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();

    params.height = 200; //fixed height
    params.width = 200; //fixed width

    getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 

    //getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(200, 200);

    Log.d("Dialog Create", "sdf3");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);

}
}
```

**dialog_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="250dp"
     >


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As you use `getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();` what do you expect to change?

Comment: I want the dialog view being displayed to be modified, but the main view is the one being affected by that code, I tried to use getDialog but got errors. `inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null)` - I want this xml to be modified

Answer (score 0):

This do the trick for me,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="250dp"
     >
```

All I need to do is to remove this codes from `onCreateView()`

```
private View getContentView() {
   View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);   

    return rootView;
}
```